# Checkbox binding in ng-repeat angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

https://jsfiddle.net/bngk/7urrobaa/

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="item.showCb = item.value == 'true' || item.value == 'false'">

<input type="checkbox" ng-if="item.showCb" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="item.value" ng-checked="item.value == 'true'">{{items[$index].value}}</input>
    <input type="text" ng-if="!item.showCb"  ng-model="item.value"/>
  </div>
```

I have problem in binding the checkboxes in ng-repeat if I have few checked values by default where the values are not properly updated in the model and if all are non-checked by default, it works but the value is updated in the model, it holds boolean value though i mentioned ng-true-value="true" and ng-false-value="false" as string. I want the string value to be present in the model. Please check in my fiddle. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code... `<input>` is a *self* closing **tag**, `ngModel` and `ngChecked` shouldn't be used together. `ngInit` isn't for this purpose..

Comment: Self closing tag and ng-init is fine. But without ng-checked, I am not able to set the values by default and without ng-model I am not able to bind the values. Please let me know how to use ng-model & ng-checked in this case...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D, you can see ng-*-value accepts an expression. So if you simply put `ng-true-value="true"`, it sees that true as an expression.

If you put `ng-true-value=" 'true' "`, then it knows it is a string.

But as mentioned above, there are a couple of other mistakes in your code.